# Module build failed in webpack

Tags: webpack, sass

Actually I dont have any idea why webpack cannot resolve my pictures and fonts.
[image]
For some reasons it cannot probably resolve path of my files.
If I add picture of font from internet, everything works ok, but reading local files webpack gives such error

[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you also share the repo's structure at least for both styles file and images dir?

Comment: https://disk.yandex.ru/client/recent?idApp=client&dialog=slider&idDialog=%2Fdisk%2Fpict.png
Check the picture of my structure here, please

Comment: Let’s share it as part of your question then